# Format date to include day of week

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server 2012 query that converts date to `VARCHAR`

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), dbo.Download.Date_of_Download, 107) as Date_to_Display,
    dbo.Download.Number_of_Computers
FROM dbo.Download
ORDER BY dbo.Download.Date_of_Download DESC
```

Below are results

```
Date_to_Display Number_of_Computers
-----------------------------------
Aug 14, 2014    240
Aug 13, 2014    519
Aug 12, 2014    622
Aug 11, 2014    2132
Aug 10, 2014    1255
Aug 09, 2014    3240
```

How do I include day of week, i.e. Saturday, Aug 09, 2014 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
select datename(dw,getdate())
```

output:

```
------------------------------
Thursday

(1 row(s) affected)
```

using your query:

```
SELECT 
    Datename(dw, dbo.Download.Date_of_Download)+', '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), dbo.Download.Date_of_Download, 107) as Date_to_Display,
    dbo.Download.Number_of_Computers
FROM dbo.Download
ORDER BY dbo.Download.Date_of_Download DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server version 2012 and later, there is the `FORMAT` TSQL function that can do what you want. The "dddd" portion does day of the week:

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(dbo.Download.Date_of_Download, 'dddd MMM dd, yyyy') as Date_to_Display,
    dbo.Download.Number_of_Computers
FROM dbo.Download
ORDER BY dbo.Download.Date_of_Download DESC
```

MS docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql